# what is wrong with this SQL statement?

Tags: mysql

```
PreparedStatement pstmt2 = conn.prepareStatement("CREATE TABLE " + getThread() +" (`Id` INT(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`name` VARCHAR(65) NOT NULL,`comment` LONGTEXT NOT NULL,`date` VARCHAR(65) NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)) COLLATE=`utf8_general_ci` ENGINE=InnoDB;");
```

i'm trying to excute a create statement but i keep getting

> You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'news (`Id`
>   INT(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`name` VARCHAR(65) NOT NULL,`comment` '

and i dont see what i'm doing wrong!
 why am i getting this error?

Comment: *"what is wrong with this block of code?"* Its not formatted in a readable way. Please format it.

Comment: don't use ` for varchars. use `'`. also if you create a table, the column names are no strings you have to mark as such.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer, its not for varchars, its for column names, but you are correct

Comment: Don't use backticks for literal strings, only for column names (and those are not strictly necessary, either).

Comment: Please provide the String what the "prepareStatement" actually receives as a parameter (query).

Comment: Incidentally INT(4) probably doesn't do whatever you think it does.

Comment: Your code is not descriptive enough to answer your question. Would you be able to System.out the query before executing and share with us?

Comment: @Strawberry changed INT to (11) and i'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Is there some reason why you refuse to show the generated query? Or *at least* the exact value that `getThread()` returns.

Comment: `getThread` return `news` and maybe something before it

Comment: @jjj here's the return:  CREATE TABLE politics news(Id INT(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, name VARCHAR(65) NOT NULL, comment LONGTEXT NOT NULL, date VARCHAR(65) NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (Id)) COLLATE='utf8_general_ci' ENGINE=InnoDB;

Comment: Well you can't have spaces in table names, can you? "politics news" is an invalid table name.

Comment: Why do you derive table name from thread name? But that is another discussion.

Comment: comment seems to be a keyword im MySql and my not be used as a column name.

Comment: You cannot have spaces in table names (well, you *can*, but best not to)

Answer (score 1):

This query has correct syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE politics_news(ID INT(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, name VARCHAR(65) NOT NULL, comment LONGTEXT NOT NULL, date VARCHAR(65) NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (Id)) COLLATE='utf8_general_ci' ENGINE=InnoDB
```

checked it on this site: https://de.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/

i am not sure if your `getThread()` return a string or something else. in case of a string use this: `getThread().replace(" ","_")` otherwise parse it to a string